# Can I change the zoom shortcut for nodes?

Tags: node-editor, shortcut

Am I just missing it or is it not possible to change the zoom shortcut for the node window from ctrl+middle mouse to alt+middle mouse? I spend the majority of my day working in Nuke which has the same thing mapped on alt and middle mouse, and it would be really nice to have it the same way in Blender.

Answer (score 3):

The zoom setting you're looking for is not in the *Node Editor* section, it's in the *View2D* section:

[image: keymap zoom for node editor]